# Fibration preserved by Base Change to Generic Fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, schemes

Let $f: S \to B$ be a ***fibration*** from an integral surface $S$ to integral curve $B$.

Here I use following definitions:

A surface (resp. curve) is a $2$-dim (resp. $1$-dim) proper $k$ scheme over fixed field $k$.

Fibration has two properties:

1. $O_B = f_*O_S$
2. all fibers of $f$ are geometrically connected

Now I wan't to see why the property 1. is "stable" with respect to the generic fiber; namely if we benote by $\eta \in B$ the unique generic point of $B$ and $S_{\eta}:=f^{-1}(\eta)$ it's fiber and by $g: S_{\eta} \to \eta$ the corresponding induced map then I wan't to know why

$$O_{k(\eta)}= g_* O_{S_{\eta}}$$

holds?

Some remarks:

Note that as scheme $\eta= Spec(k(\eta))$.

Futhermore if we denote the canonical immersions $i_B: \eta \to B$ and $i_S: S_{\eta} \to S$.

My attempts:

Firstly, how is the structure sheaf of $S_{\eta}$ is concretely defined. My intuitive choice would be $O_{S_{\eta}}= O_S \otimes_k k(\eta)$. Is this correct?

Now the problem (in order to verify $O_{k(\eta)}= g_* O_{S_{\eta}}$):

Let $U$ be open in $\eta$ so wlog $U= \eta$.

I have to show that $g_* O_{S_{\eta}}(\eta)=k(\eta)$(= $O_{k(\eta)}(\eta)$)

Then I proceed using definitions and that $i_B \circ g = f \circ i_S$ by construction:

$$g_* O_{S_{\eta}}(\eta)= g_* O_{S_{\eta}}(i_b^{-1}(\eta))= {i_B} _* g_*O_{S_{\eta}}(\eta)=f_* {i_S} _* O_{S_{\eta}}(\eta)= {i_S} _* O_{S_{\eta}}(S_{\eta})= {i_S} _* O_S \otimes_k k(\eta)(S_{\eta})= O_S(S) \otimes_k k(\eta)$$

And exactly this is the problem: I don't see why $O_S(S) \otimes_k k(\eta)= k(\eta)$.

Does anybody see where is the error in my reasonings?

Comment: The point $\eta$ is not open in $B$.

Comment: @user45878: Yes, if $\eta \to B$ would be an open immeresion then the statement would be trivial. The main obstuction was to derive the stucture sheaf of $S_{\eta}$ althought $S_{\eta}$ is neither open nor closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier than you're making it. As $\eta$ is a point, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{O}_{S_\eta}(S_\eta)=k(\eta)$. As proper and fibers geometrically connected is preserved under fiber product, the map $g:S_\eta\to \eta$ is proper, so all global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{S_\eta}$ are constant in the fiber direction on each connected component. This means that the global sections are a vector space of dimension equal to the number of geometric connected components, but $S_\eta$ is geometrically connected. Thus $\mathcal{O}_{S_\eta}(S_\eta)=k(\eta)$ and the proof is finished.

Comment: What do you mean by "all global sections of $O_{S_η}$ are constant in the fiber direction"?  Why is it a consequence of properness? Sorry, if it is from analytical point of view a triviality but hornestly I'm only familar with algebraic and algebro-topological approach to the the concept of global sections. Could you explain the picture which one should have if one talks about global sections (analytically understood as functions defined on whole space) where the whole space is contracted to a point by a ***proper*** map. Why are the functions then at each connected component constant?

Comment: Is there also an algebraic meaning behind it?

Comment: Yes. Proper varieties are complete, so the image of any proper variety under a map of varieties is closed and complete. But a global section is just a map to $\Bbb A^1$, and $\Bbb A^1$ is _never_ complete, so a global section of a complete variety has to have image which is a proper closed subset of $\Bbb A^1$. In the case where you're working over a field, this means it's a finite collection of points, and you can see that this is exactly the situation that happens with any fiber over a point of a proper morphism. So any global function is constant in the fiber direction.